# Redis - How to completely flush/clear memory after a flushdb?

Tags: redis

After doing several `flushdb` on a Redis database, I wonder how to completely flush/clear the memory use ?

Indeed, I made some tests :

- watching memory with a `htop` -> 800 Mo used
- fill in a Redis database -> goes to 1500 Mo used
- flushing the database => memory use stay at about 1500 Mo...

Any ideas ?  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server and running flushall (if you want to remove all data)?

Answer (score 32):

Try using [flushall](http://redis.io/commands/flushall)

Comment: ```redis-cli flushall```